# How to invoke multiple intents with a single utterance in Amazon Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I would like to chain (i.e., activate consecutively) multiple intents using a single utterance in Amazon Lex.

For example: "Grab a screenshot, then convert to grayscale, then save to the cloud". "Grab a screenshot", "Convert to grayscale", and "Save to the cloud" are three distinct intents.

As I understand this is not currently possible with Amazon Lex. What would be the best way to implement this kind of "scripting" behavior that would allow queueing intents?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a dialog to collect actions and have your intent handler calling one separate piece of code (Javacsript/python function) per action.

- Grab a screentshot
- ok, Il will grab a screen shot, is there anything else you want to do ?
- convert to grayscale
- Noted, I will also convert the screenshot to grayscale, anything else ?
- save to the cloud
- No problem, your grayscale screenshot will be save to the cloud.